# css changing link background on hover

Tags: html, css, nav

I want to make my links' background change color when hovered. I know there are lots forums but somehow I have checked few forums.
I think I do understand the logics but somehow when I try to implement it to my site somehow I couldn't get it to work. Only the link's background changes the color not the whole li changes.

```
    div.panel.widget.widget_nav_menu {width: 100%; background-color: #EBDDE2;}
    div.panel.widget.widget_nav_menu ul {width: 100%; list-style-type: none;}
    div.panel.widget.widget_nav_menu a {width: 100%; margin-left: 25px;}
    div.panel.widget.widget_nav_menu a:hover {background-color: #EFE4E8;}
```

Can someone give me a hand what I have been missing?
here is a link [beaucare-clinical-facial](http://beaucare.ca/?portfolio=clinical-facials) of where the navigation is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On thing  you could try is changing the `display` property of the links from `inline` (which is the default) to `block`. The link should then take up the full width of its container object (in this case, the `li`). For example:

```
widget_nav_menu a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 25%;
}
```

This approach is slightly better than changing the colour of the `li` as people expect the entire area that changes colour to be clickable.

Also, there's no real need to be so specific with your CSS selectors. If you remove `div.panel.widget` they should all still work just fine.

Comment: omg thanks I am so stupid to miss the `display:block` I am thinking of adding the ul class into it because there are are different navigation menu created in wp I don't want it to target to all navigations :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Trgeting "anchor" tag, target to LI

check this

```
 div.panel.widget.widget_nav_menu {width: 100%; background-color: #EBDDE2;}
    div.panel.widget.widget_nav_menu ul {width: 100%; list-style-type: none;}
    div.panel.widget.widget_nav_menu a {width: 100%; margin-left: 25px;}
    div.panel.widget.widget_nav_menu li:hover {background-color: #EFE4E8;}
```

Comment: @Dora : i checked it in your website n my fix is working perfectly

Comment: sorry I tried his way first >.<" but I thought your way it'll hover hover over li but then the link wouldn't work unless mouse points to where the anchor is.